# How to set password for hdd partition mounting

Tags: 13.04, mount, filesystem, fstab, udisks

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64.

I have one extra ext4 partition of 90 GB beside my `/` partition.
I want to ask the user to enter a password whenever he/she tries to mount that extra partition by say
1) clicking on it in nautilus left hand column or
2) using command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An effective way would be to encrypt that partition.

Take a look at `luks` and `cryptsetup`. You will find a lot of information about that when you Google it.

If I remember correctly, nautilus will ask you for the password when you click at the not yet unlocked drive. If that does not work you can always create a shell script for that task.

That should be the most straight forward and secure solution to your problem. If you need more help, let me know.

Good luck!